# does 960-gs auto clear floats?

Tags: 960.gs, compass-sass

Does the 960-plugin in compass auto-clear floats? I would assume so, but I'm having trouble with my layout right now, so I am guessing I have to explicitly clear it using the compass clear mixin?

Comment: maybe post a jsfiddle or example?

Comment: its just a basic question of if the framework has it or none. i added the compass clear mixin to fix my styles but just wanted to know if the plugin has it innately or if i did the correct thing by adding the mixin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it doesn't have it. I checked the source code and saw this:

```
=grid-container
  margin-left: auto
  margin-right: auto
  width: $ninesixty-grid-width
```

no clearfix in sight